# Dequantize values to their original prior to quantization

Tags: python, tensorflow, math, pytorch, quantization

The paper "Natural Language Processing with Small Feed-Forward Networks" https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.00214.pdf states:

[image]

I've implemented quantization as per the above equations in python:

```
b = 128

embedding_matrix = [[20000,3000,1000],[1999999,20000,1999999], [20000,3000,1000]]

scaled = [ abs(round( (1 / (b - 1) * max(e)) , 3)) for e in embedding_matrix]

print(scaled)

i = 0

quantized = []
for e in embedding_matrix :
    for v in e : 
        quantized.append((v , math.floor(.5 + ( (v / scaled[i]) + b) )))
    i = i + 1
    
quantized
```

Running this code `quantized` is set to :

```
[(20000, 255),
 (3000, 147),
 (1000, 134),
 (1999999, 255),
 (20000, 129),
 (1999999, 255),
 (20000, 255),
 (3000, 147),
 (1000, 134)]
```

How to de-quantize back to the original values prior to quantization ?

Reading https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/quantization/dequantize describes :

```
tf.quantization.dequantize(
    input, min_range, max_range, mode='MIN_COMBINED', name=None, axis=None,
    narrow_range=False, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32
)

[min_range, max_range] are scalar floats that specify the range for the output. The 'mode' attribute controls exactly which calculations are used to convert the float values to their quantized equivalents.
```

and the PyTorch docs: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/quantization.html

Seems to implement quantize differently to above implementation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What they are doing in the paper is roughly this:

```
import numpy as np

b = 128

embedding_matrix = np.array([[20000,3000,1000,1000],[1999999,20000,1999999,1999999], [20000,3000,1000,1000]])
scales = (np.abs(embedding_matrix).max(axis=1) / (b-1)).reshape(-1, 1)
quantized = (embedding_matrix / scales + b + 0.5).astype(np.uint8)
dequantized = (quantized - b) * scales
print(quantized)
print(dequantized)
```

Output:

```
[[255 147 134 134]
 [255 129 255 255]
 [255 147 134 134]]
[[2.00000000e+04 2.99212598e+03 9.44881890e+02 9.44881890e+02]
 [1.99999900e+06 1.57480236e+04 1.99999900e+06 1.99999900e+06]
 [2.00000000e+04 2.99212598e+03 9.44881890e+02 9.44881890e+02]]
```

In short they just have `q_ij = round(e_ij / s_i + b)`, so after you just have quantized value `q_ij` your best approximation is to say that `q_ij = dequantized_ij / s_i + b`, so `dequantized_ij = (q_ij - b) * s_i`

As to pytorch - similar functionality is available with `torch.quantize_per_channel` e.g the following code is doing pretty much the same:

```
import torch
t = torch.tensor(embedding_matrix, dtype=torch.float32)
zero_point = torch.tensor([b]).repeat(t.shape[0], 1).reshape(-1)
quantized_tensor = torch.quantize_per_channel(t, t.abs().max(axis=1)[0] / (b-1), zero_point, 0, torch.quint8)
print(quantized_tensor)
print(quantized_tensor.int_repr())
```

Output:

```
tensor([[2.0000e+04, 2.9921e+03, 9.4488e+02, 9.4488e+02],
        [2.0000e+06, 1.5748e+04, 2.0000e+06, 2.0000e+06],
        [2.0000e+04, 2.9921e+03, 9.4488e+02, 9.4488e+02]], size=(3, 4),
       dtype=torch.quint8, quantization_scheme=torch.per_channel_affine,
       scale=tensor([  157.4803, 15748.0234,   157.4803], dtype=torch.float64),
       zero_point=tensor([128, 128, 128]), axis=0)
tensor([[255, 147, 134, 134],
        [255, 129, 255, 255],
        [255, 147, 134, 134]], dtype=torch.uint8)
```

If quantized per channel like this in pytorch you can only apply `.dequantize()` on the full tensor rather then the sliced which wouldn't be a good thing for embeddings, but you can do it manually very easy using `repr_int`, `q_per_channel_zero_points`, and `q_per_channel_scales`.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: So it's really just de-scaling, not de-quantizing?

Comment: Well, this is just simple linear quantization. To store values as uint8 they are pretty much scaling them to fit into 0-255 range and rounded to nearest integer.

Comment: Since we already lost precision by truncating part of the number the only thing we can do to restore the value it represent is to scale it back. So it is de-quantizing which  only has to apply de-scaling (+ translation since zero is represented by `b`).

Comment: @AlexanderPivovarov what ensures the values are scaled to fit into the 0-255 range ? Is it related to the bias b value (128) ?

Comment: Yes, also the values will never be 0 (that seems to be consistent with PyTorch implementation as well, and PyTorch is reserving 0 quantized value for things like `nan`, `inf`). Due to the way how the scales are defined, the value `e_ij / s_i` (in the paper's terms) is guaranteed to be between `-(b-1)` and `b-1`, then after adding `0.5 + b` it will be between `1.5` and `2b - 0.5` - so after truncating to integer it will always be between `1` and `2b-1` so in this case between `1` and `255`. Zero value will be always quantized as `b` i.e. `128` here.

Comment: @AlexanderPivovarov why is "the value e_ij / s_i (in the paper's terms) is guaranteed to be between -(b-1) and b-1" ? Is it because of how 's_i' , the scale factor is calculated ?

Comment: @blue-sky yes, `s_i` is defined as `1/(b-1) * max_j (abs(e_ij))`. Start from `abs(e_ij) <= max_j (abs(e_ij))`, then divide both sides by `s_i` and you get `abs(e_ij / s_i) <= max_j (abs(e_ij)) / s_i`. But we know that `max_j (abs(e_ij)) / s_i` is equal to `b-1`, so we get `abs(e_ij / s_i) <= (b-1)` and thus `-(b-1) <= e_ij / s_i <= b-1`. It is important to note that this type of quantization is not updated dynamically - it is just applied after the weights were trained to store trained model in a more compact way.